# Extract rows, wrt to a spedific condition, for every group/id in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the below dataset

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd

#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,
               4, 4, 4, 4,4,
               5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5,5,     5,5, 5,5, 5, 5,5],
        'cycle': [0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,
                   0.2,0.4, 0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,
                   0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,
                  0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,
                  0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,   2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0,3.2],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   4, 4, 4,4,5,6,
                   8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
                   8,9,10,11,12,
                   7, 7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
        'Children': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes','Yes',
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','Yes',
                      'No',  'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',    'No',  'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 141,
                 141,123, 128, 66,67,
                 123, 128, 66, 123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,   123, 128, 66, 123, 128, 66, 120,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("\n df = \n",df)
```

The above dataset looks as such:

[image]

Here for every 'id', I wish to extract only those rows, whose 'cycle' is an integer value, as shown in the boxes of the above image file.

The expected dataframe is as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in Pyhton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to work per group, just filter the integers:

```
# is the cycle an integer?
m = df['cycle'].round().eq(df['cycle'])

# keep those rows
out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
    id  cycle  Salary Children  Days
4    1    1.0       9      Yes   120
9    1    2.0      14      Yes   141
15   2    1.0       5      Yes    52
21   3    1.0      12       No   120
28   4    1.0      12      Yes    67
33   5    1.0      11      Yes   128
38   5    2.0       9       No   123
43   5    3.0      14      Yes    66
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how do I reset the index in the Output from 0 to 7.

Comment: `out = df[m].reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the dataframe according to one column, in your case, the cycle column.

```
df_selected = df.loc[df.loc[:, "cycle"] % 1 == 0]
```

This will only select those rows in which cycle divided by 1 will have no remainder, which is only true for integers. I am not quite sure if that could ever cause problems with precision due to floating point numbers, but with the little testing I did, it worked fine. Output is

```
    id  cycle  Salary Children  Days 
[4    1    1.0       9      Yes   120] 
[9    1    2.0      14      Yes   141] 
[15   2    1.0       5      Yes    52] 
[21   3    1.0      12       No   120] 
[28   4    1.0      12      Yes    67] 
[33   5    1.0      11      Yes   128] 
[38   5    2.0       9       No   123] 
[43   5    3.0      14      Yes    66]
```